# About bra-ket notation and hermitian operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators

I have a question about matrix elements bra-ket notations and ladder operators.
Does
$$⟨0|aa^\dagger|0⟩ = ⟨0|aa^\dagger aa^\dagger|0⟩=0~?$$

Answer (score 1):

If you use $[a,a^\dagger]=1$, it is easy to see that
$$
\langle 0|aa^\dagger|0\rangle=\langle 0|a^\dagger a|0\rangle
+1=1\ne 0.$$

Comment: Similarly, the second inner product is the squared length of $aa^\dagger|0\rangle=a|1\rangle=|0\rangle$, i.e. $1$.

Comment: What about $<0|a+a^{\dagger}|0>$ and $<1|a+a^{\dagger}|0>$?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Look at the comment by @J.G. You will get $\langle 0|a+a^\dagger|0\rangle=0$. I have left the other as an exercise.